# Jquery datapicker localization using globalize plugin

Tags: jquery, localization, globalization, jquery-ui-datepicker, javascript-globalize

Is it possible localize jquery datapicker using globalize plugin (https://github.com/jquery/globalize)?

I tried in this way

```
// get a date format 
var dt = Globalize.culture().calendar.patterns.d;
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    dateFormat : dt
});
```

but it does not work because datepicker and globalize plugin use two format different.

I want the date with 2 digits for the month, 2 digits for the day and 4 digits for the year, so in jquery the date format must be "dd/mm/yy". But globalize use a different date format:
en-Us -> M/d/yyyy
it-IT -> dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: BTW. globalize3 tag, refers to Ruby On Rails extension, rather than Globalize script.

Answer (score 5):

Small converter:

```
Globalize.getPatternForDatapicker = function (pattern) {
    return this.culture().calendar.patterns[pattern || 'd'].toLowerCase().replace('yyyy', 'yy');
};
```

and

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({dateFormat : Globalize.getPatternForDatapicker()});
```

Comment: But this only sets the date pattern, yes? Localization requires also getting all the month names, week names, etc.  All that data is in the globalize.culture.xx-XX.js files, but is there a way to use it?

Answer (score 1):

In the [early days of Globalize](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx) (called back then jQuery Globalize) there was specifically [patched version of Datepicker](http://www.scottgu.com/blogposts/jQueryGlobalizationDemos.zip) available.
Frankly, I don't think it is usable anymore, but you may try to apply the same modifications to current version and the problem will be resolved. This could be done quite easy with a diff command available with many Unix-like systems (and on Windows via Cygwin for example).

---

#### Edit: API

I think it is at least good to mention, that Datepicker is offering rich [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/).
You can use to tailor down Datepicker's Localization. However, when it comes to date format, I am afraid that you would be forced to use some replacement to remove "excessive" y's from year field. That's something I would prefer not to do, instead I would patch Datepicker, as suggested previously, but...

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into many problems of those two format discrepancies.
Finally jQuery guys replied me they would switch to Globalize format using. However, when... :(